# Is it possible to specify the direction of rotation in VectorAngle function?

Tags: vector, rotation

If I use the function VectorAngle[{1,0},{1,-1}], is it possible to obtain the angle generated by rotating around the axis counter clock wise?  In other words, I would move from the first vector to the second in the positive direction.  My output would be (7/4)*Pi instead of Pi/4.

Comment: How about `2 Pi - VectorAngle[{1, 0}, {1, -1}]`?

Comment: Is there a way to specify what direction I moved with respect to the first vector?

Answer (score 7):

Not with `VectorAngle` alone. One way to go about this:

```
directedangle[a_, b_] := 
 If[Sign@Det[{a, b}] >= 0, VectorAngle[a, b], 2 π - VectorAngle[a, b]]

directedangle[{1, 0}, {1, 1}]
directedangle[{1, 0}, {-1, 1}]
directedangle[{1, 0}, {1, -1}]
```

> π/4
>
> (3 π)/4
>
> (7 π)/4

Comment: very nice, but the format of the output is not correct (confusing) :)

Comment: @eldo sorry my symbol toolbar is not working right now.

Comment: @Öskå - thanks for the edit (mine was only a quick fix)

Comment: @Öska thx - editing from a mobile phone is a royal pain :-)

Comment: @eldo [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor/1333#1333) helps a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

`ArcTan` version:

```
 (If[# < 0, # + 2 Pi , #] &@(-Subtract @@ (ArcTan @@ # & /@ #))) & /@
      {{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {-1, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {1, -1}}}
```

> {Pi/4, (3 Pi)/4, (7 Pi)/4}

or to put in the function form of the other answer:

```
 directedangle[a_, b_] :=
    (If[# < 0, # + 2 Pi, #] &@(-Subtract @@ (ArcTan @@ # & /@ {a, b})))
```

Comment: would it be possible to find an algorithm for the second line of your answer?

Comment: Would someone be able to parse this last solution for me? I think I know what the various operators do, but I can't tell how to group them.

Answer (score 2):

For the directional angle I am using a simplified version.
To get -1/4 Pi instead of 7/4 Pi is OK!

```
directedangle[a_, b_]:= Sign@Det[{a, b}] VectorAngle[a, b]

directedangle[{1, 0}, {1, 1}]
directedangle[{1, 0}, {-1, 1}]
directedangle[{1, 0}, {1, -1}]
```

> `Pi/4`
>   `(3 Pi)/4`
>   `-Pi/4`